# ASP.NET and PNG from root not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, png, http-status-code-404

I am baffled but why wouldnt http://usayouthhoops.com/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png work, even though it's in the root?  I keep getting a 404 error.  I update the extension to .JPG and it works.  This happens on IIS and my local VS server.  I'm not doing anything special with routes.

Comment: in IIS ..is the mime type for PNG properly defined?

Comment: Yes the mime type is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Have anything in your web.config that is preventing any particular content from being served from the root?  Also try to manually delete your bin and obj folders, rebuilding and checking again.

...